# Spring Autoconfiguration Issues with Tomcat vs. Jetty

Tags: spring, tomcat, configuration, jetty

I am creating an application with websockets where I use Spring's autoconfiguration ability via the @EnableAutoConfiguration annotation before my main class. I am attempting to use Tomcat because that is what I am familiar with. I am using apache camel to route my messages and the camel dependencies have a lot of jetty jars in them.

The jetty jars are forcing the autoconfiguration in spring to start a jetty instance rather than a tomcat one and I was wondering if there was any way to add parameters or anything else to the autoconfiguration annotation that would ensure it worked how I needed and started the Tomcat instance regardless of the jars in my dependencies. I tried excluding all of the jetty jars, but it still wouldn't revert to Tomcat like it was before I added the back end camel to my application.

Any advice? Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Comment: Fix your question.  Jetty 7+ supports WebSockets (Jetty API). Jetty 9.1+ supports JSR-356 (javax.websocket API)

Comment: Just fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml?